# An expression of complex numbers and finding values of them

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ z = \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi}{7} \right) + i\sin\left( \frac{2 \pi}{7}\right) $ be a complex number in polar form
and $ A = z + z^2 + z^4 , B = z^3 + z^5 + z^6 $

then  $ AB $  $ = $ $ ? $

I found simply expanding, a lengthy process.
What can be a simple way to evaluate this? I am beginner to complex numbers.

$ ****** $

Property I know:

$ zz' = \vert z \vert ^2 $

where $ z' $ is conjugate of $ z $

Comment: use the theorem of Moivre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z^7=1$,$$AB=z^4+z^5+z^6+3z^7+z^8+z^9+z^{10}=3+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=2.$$because$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=\frac{z^7-1}{z-1}=0.$$

Comment: I thought he was trying to avoid this. But nevermind.

Comment: @samjoe Why? I saw no sign of that.

Comment: I meant opening up brackets

Comment: Sir, how you concluded the third equality?

Comment: @MaanavRoy Since $z^7=1$, $z^8=z^7.z=z$, $z^9=z^7.z^2=z^2$, and $z^{10}=z^7.z^3=z^3$.

Comment: Complex numbers are either purely real or imaginary(or both), but you are purely great legend!

Answer (score 1):

An approach to reduce the length of the problem is to notice that $1,z,...,z^6$ are the seven roots of $z^7-1=0$. If you've been taught these problems, you'll know that $z,z^6$ and $z^2,z^5$ and $z^3,z^4$ are conjugates of each other (visualize on the Argand plane)

Thus, $A=z+z^2+\bar{z^3}$ and $B=z^3+\bar{z^2}+\bar{z}$. So, $A=\bar{B}$.

Thus, $AB=\bar{B}B=|B|^2=|z^3(1+z^2+z^3)|^2=|(1+z^2+z^3)|^2$ ($\because  |z|=1$ )

Now, put the values of $1,z^2,z^3$ and solve.

Comment: This approach is good if you do NOT wish to open up the parentheses in the first place. If you do, however, then Jose's answer is the way to go.